# Is there a PHP function to remove any/all key/value pairs that have a certain value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I think questions like this are the reason why I don't like working with PHP. The manual is good, if you can find what you are looking for. After reading through the [Array Functions](https://www.php.net/array), I didn't see one that provides the functionality I need.

I have an array (in my case, numerically indexed) that I want to scan for a particular value and, if it's there, remove it. And then, when all instances of that value have been removed, I want to rearrange the array using [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted...

Comment: Yea, me too. Perhaps because of your implied criticism of the language … ah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_diff`](http://de.php.net/array_diff) is what you want.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Result: `"blue"`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would have helped if this was called something like array_prune, array_remove, or something else more descriptive. Thanks again.

Comment: I agree that the PHP (array) function names are somewhat arbitrary and inconsistent. I've often spent a lot of time searching for the right function myself.

Comment: Especially when I don't open every function and read the details. I didn't even know from "Computes the difference of arrays" that this function returned an array, so I discarded it and kept reading on. I thought it might return an integer diff, like a levenshein (sp?) distance between arrays.

Comment: Yeah - I thought it'd give a result of all elements which appear in only one array. It appears not.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this...

array_diff appears to show elements in the first array which don't appear in the second array. It doesn't show those elements which only appear in one or the other array.

e.g.

```
<?
$test = "hello";
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "bicycle", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "yellow", "pink");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r ($result);
?>
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [1] => bicycle
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the array_diff function, but I have my one scripted one if you dont want to pass down an array:

```
function array_unset_value($value, &$array) {
    $key = array_search($value, $array);
    while ($key !== false) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        $key = array_search($value, $array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_filter does this for you. You just need to provide a filter callback function:

```
function myFilter($Value){
   if($Value == 'red'){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

$Values = array("a" => "green", "red", "bicycle", "red");

$Values = array_filter($Values, 'myFilter');
```

returns:

```
array {
  ["a"] => "green"
  [1]   => "bicycle"
}
```

The filter function should return true for values you want to keep and false for those you wish to remove. Then just go ahead and use array_values to re-index the array. e.g.

```
$Values = array_values(array_filter($Values, 'myFilter'));
```

If you are doing this within an object and you want to call a filter method within the object you can use this form for the callback:

```
array_filter($Values, array($this,'myFilter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild this "impossible" function, I'd suggest :
function pf_cleanarray($arraytoclean=false,$to_explode=false,$delimiter=false) {
/* PortalPress.org 2011 [maintain this comment, please] - cleans up an array upto to NULL or makes an array with content; use with care and better not use on even length depending [associative] arrays


It looks terrible, I know, especially without indent on Stackoverflow. But when rebuilding, it can be a very useful, dynamic tool, using just the simplest functions, so you will be able to manipulate keys and values at will on a multi-array. The keyfunction is to delete empty values or make an array with explode, that's clean, but with a little trouble, it can be made into a function that eliminates the elements depending on key or value. - Igor M. -


Simple example:
$A[0][0][0][0][0][0]="A";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][0]="";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][0]="";
$A[0][0][0][0][0][1]="";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][1]="";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][1]="";
$A[0][0][0][0][0][2]="";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][2]="";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][2]="";
$A[0][0][0][0][0][3]="";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][3]="";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][3]="";
$A[0][0][0][0][0][4]="";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][4]="";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][4]="";
$A[0][0][0][0][0][5]="";
$A[1][0][0][0][0][5]="A";
$A[2][0][0][0][0][5]="";
The $A array:
Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>A[1]=>[2]=>[3]=>[4]=>[5]=>)))))
      [1]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>[1]=>[2]=>[3]=>[4]=>[5]=>A)))))
      [2]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>[1]=>[2]=>[3]=>[4]=>[5]=>))))))
Results in $A:
Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>A)))))
      [1]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Array([0]=>A))))))
*/
if($arraytoclean===0 || $arraytoclean) {
    if(!is_array($arraytoclean)) {
        if($to_explode && $delimiter) {
            $arraytoclean=explode($delimiter,$arraytoclean);
        } else {
            $arraytoclean=Array($arraytoclean);
        }
    }
    $nZx=0;
    $keyarray=array_keys($arraytoclean);
    for($nYx=0;$nYx
        $keydigit=true;
        if($keyarray[$nYx]!==$nYx) {
            $keydigit=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    for($nYx=0;$nYx
        if(!is_array($arraytoclean[$keyarray[$nYx]])) {
            if($arraytoclean[$keyarray[$nYx]]) {
                if(!isset($retarraytoclean)) {
                    $retarraytoclean=Array();
                }
                $retarraytoclean[(($keydigit) ?  $nZx : $keyarray[$nYx])]=$arraytoclean[$keyarray[$nYx]];
                $nZx++;
            }
        } else {
            $temparr=pf_cleanarray($arraytoclean[$keyarray[$nYx]]);
            if($temparr) {
                if(!isset($retarraytoclean)) {
                    $retarraytoclean=Array();
                }
                $retarraytoclean[(($keydigit) ?  $nZx : $keyarray[$nYx])]=$temparr;
                $nZx++;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(isset($retarraytoclean)) {
    return($retarraytoclean);
} else {
    return(NULL);
}
}

Comment: M - indent code 4 spaces or select and use the `{}` button. See markdown [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more.

Comment: I tried to edit your code for formatting, but .. couldn't. Also, there's no need for comments like `/* PortalPress.org 2011 [maintain this comment, please] */`, since using _anything_ from Stack Overflow requires attribution under the terms of our license. If someone uses this code, they have to link to this answer, as well as your user page. There's no need to introduce additional restrictions.