# create_function in php

Tags: php, create-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a PHP function to remove any/all key/value pairs that have a certain value from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225560/is-there-a-php-function-to-remove-any-all-key-value-pairs-that-have-a-certain-va)
>   [Remove zero values from a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287404/remove-zero-values-from-a-php-array)

I have one array like this.

```
[notify_emp] => Array
  (
      [224] => 0
      [228] => 0
      [232] => 1
      [250] => 1
      [350] => 1
  )
```

I want only those keys from the array which have value set to 1 and need to remove keys that have value 0. 
how can I do this using create_function in php ? or is there any other way to perform the action?

Comment: I don't see why you want to use `create_function` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function hasOne($var)
{
    // returns whether the input has 1
    return($var == 1);
}


$arr= array("224"=>1, "228"=>0, "250" => 1);

print_r(array_filter($arr, "hasOne"));
?>
```

Which results in:

```
Array ( [224] => 1 [250] => 1 )
```

Comment: Note that `array_filter` doesn't need a callback in this case; it defaults to filtering out all items with value equivalent to `FALSE` upon conversion to a boolean.

Comment: You are right, after this post, I did some more research, all you need is `array_filter($arr)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_filter($array, create_function('$val', 'return (bool) $val;'));
```

...or for PHP >= 5.3:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function ($val) {
  return (bool) $val;
});
```

...or simply (as @outis rightly points out) you can simply

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

...or you could just:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  if (!$v) unset($array[$k]);
}
```

Take your pick.

However, I guess what you want is a list of items with an "on" flag, so this might be a better approach:

```
$flaggedAsOn = array_keys($array,'1');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3 then using array_filter with an anonymous function is a lot less mucking around.

If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.3 then just implementing a function for use as a callback with array_filter is less mucking around than using create_function().

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_unwanted ($array) {

   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

      if ($array[$key] == '0') { unset($array[$key]) }

   }

}
```